# import android.content.SharedPreferences; error

Tags: java

Check out the error - 
[SceenShot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pya78.png)

This is error.I found in my premanager file.This problem cause me in my automatically close  some of activity?.I rebuild project again but unable to solve the problem.check out screenshot and code below

```java
package com.player.gamezwin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;


public class PrefManager {

    // shared pref mode
    private final int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private final SharedPreferences pref;
    private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private final Context _context;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "player";

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setBoolean(String PREF_NAME,Boolean val) {
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, val);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void setString(String PREF_NAME,String VAL) {
        editor.putString(PREF_NAME, VAL);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void setInt(String PREF_NAME,int VAL) {
        editor.putInt(PREF_NAME, VAL);
        editor.commit();
    }
    public boolean getBoolean(String PREF_NAME) {
        return pref.getBoolean(PREF_NAME,true);
    }
    public String getString(String PREF_NAME) {
        if(pref.contains(PREF_NAME)){
            return pref.getString(PREF_NAME,null);
        }
        return  "";
    }
    public void remove(String PREF_NAME){
        if(pref.contains(PREF_NAME)){
            editor.remove(PREF_NAME);
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

    public int getInt(String key) {
        return pref.getInt(key,0);
    }

    public void clearall() {
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

If you need any other my file to solve the problem.Please comment below.I will happy to provide you that file.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial

Comment: Excuse me but I don't see what your error is? Your screen shot (of Android Studio) only shows code. What am I missing?